# Extracted Private Key from PFX file is rejected by SFTP Tools like Winscp or Filezilla

Tags: sftp, openssl, winscp, private-key

Long story short - I'm trying to extract the private key file from a PFX file which is used for SFTP authentication. I'm able to generate the private key file but it is not acceptable by the SFTP tools like WinSCP or FileZilla

**Approach 1:**

1. Latest version of OpenSSL
2. Latest version of WinSCP

The general command to generate Private key out of PFX file using OpenSSL. But this did not work

```
openssl pkcs12 -in C:\sample.pfx -nocerts -nodes -out C:\samplePpk.ppk
```

I was getting this error

```
803F0100: error : 0308010C: digital envelope routines:inner_evp_generic_fetch:unsupported:crypto\evp\evp_fetch.c:349:Global default library context, Algorithm(cbc) Properties ()
```

As suggested by the Stackoverflow post I ran the above command in a different way referring the legacy.dll file as below

```
openssl pkcs12 -in C:\sample.pfx -out C:\sampleOutput.ppk -nodes -nocerts -legacy -provider-path "C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64\bin" -provider default.
```

This created a PPK file output. But it had opening line like this --BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-- instead of --BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY--. I tried to convert it to RSA private KEY using the below command

```
openssl rsa -in C:\sampleOutput.ppk -out C:\sampleOutputRSA.ppk
```

But it still generated the same private key with --BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-- Now this private key is not getting imported in puttyGen or in the winscp as it gives unrecognizable format.

**Approach 2:**

1. Downgraded version of OPEN SSL - 1.1.1f
2. Downgraded version of WINSCP - 5.17.3

Extracted PPK from PFX using the below command

```
openssl pkcs12 -in C:\sampleOutput.pfx -out C:\sampleOutput.ppk -nodes -nocerts
```

It created a PPK file with --BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-- header. Then used the below command to convert it to the RSA key

```
openssl rsa -in C:\sampleOutput.ppk -out C:\sampleOutputRSA.ppk
```

And the PPK file is created with the --BEING RSA PRIVATE KEY-- header.

When used the private key in WINSCP it showed the key needs to be in putty format. I loaded the RSA key to PUTTYGEN and added a passphrase to save it as private key again.

The exported private key is now accepted by WINSCP but not authenticating it and this is the error it showed. enter image description here

I wanted to understand what I'm doing is correct or is there a different way to extract the PPK out of the PFX file.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I've deleted the question in the stackoverflow forum. The reason why im doing this is, I've got an PFX file from the client who has a certificate and private key inside it. This private key has to be used as a authentication to access their SFTP data. Hence I need to extract the private key from their PFX file. Im checking id this can be opened via the Open SSH

Comment: PFX files are commonly used with TLS, not with SSH.  Aren't you supposed to use FTPS (FTP over TLS), instead of SFTP (SSH)?

Comment: It seems like it used to work with SSH. And the issue I'm receiving is strange. I'm just thinking the approach I'm following  is wrong. I'm not 100% sure

Comment: *"It seems like it used to work with SSH"* – Based on what does it seem?